# Get valid identities list on Mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, keychain

I'm using

```
security find-identity -v
```

command, but it works extremely slow on Mavericks (on 10.8 it was working much faster).
I've tried it without -v option without any luck.

Is there any other options to get such list, or how can I speed up the security utility?

I think it should be possible because when I open KeychainAccess.app it shows all identities (about 60) in about 2 seconds, when security util making it in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've ended up in writing my own utility which is using Security.framework.
Works like a charm, and very quickly!